# Vaadin grid details behaviour

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Could you please advice whether is it possible to achieve the following behavior with the Vaadin Grid details:

1. Do not show details row based on grid item content.
2. Do not collaps previously expanded details on another rows (be able to show details for more than one row).

I am using the latest release version of Vaadin 24.

Thanks in advance,
Vadim

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both.

You can toggle the visibility of the details panel manually with the `setDetailsVisible(T item, boolean visible)` method, e.g. triggered from a clicklistener on the row, depending on the item on that row.

The 2nd example in this section https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#item-details has an example of using that method, and also demonstrates having multiple details open simultaneously.